# How to preserve the exact file name upon uploading (no case change, no underscore)

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

At some point during upload the file name gets converted to the lower case and spaces are being replaced with the underscore. How do I preserve the original file name, without these 2 changes?

I've searched inside of all files for toLowerCase() and can't find it.

Comment: This sounds like a filesystem/operating system issue, nothing to do with uploading or jquery.

Comment: That was my initial thought, so I checked my server side and couldn't find anything. Perhaps I missed something, so I'll try again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel so stupid. Turned out the ABCUpload component I'm using by http://www.websupergoo.com/helpupload/ is doing the conversion. There's another property available which passes the raw file name, I just have to use that one.

Thanks Flimzy to at least pointing me to the right direction.